# Is it possible to convert Pocket articles into epub format?

Tags: epub, conversion, kobo, pocket

I'd like to know if there is an easy way to convert [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/) articles to `.epub` format.

*For those that don't know Pocket, it is a service that let's you save articles from any website, blog, and so on, and read them whenever you want on your favourite device, providing also an improved formatting for mobile devices. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_%28application%29) explains all of this nicely.*
*As an example, I usually save articles from my phone when I don't have the time to read them (or when I want to keep them for future reference), and read the later on my Kobo ereader, that has this application embedded.*

Since this service is available for a great number of devices, it is not a matter of accessibility; but if, for whatever reason, the contents should become inaccessible, I'd like to have a sort of backup ready to use; and I'm also interested about this "for the sake of science", so to say.

Is someone more informed than me about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several different possible solutions for your task. The approaches differ in terms of used tools and level of automation.

- a technically very easy way is a special [Google Chrome browser plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-pocket-to-epub/pdjnbjiohamgdeoboegachkpapngicjc) which allows an epub export within the pocket website.
- a rather automated solution is the use of pocket as [custom news source for calibre](http://getpocket.com/blog/2010/02/read-your-list-on-your-kindleebook-reader-with-calibre/).
- And last but also as rather a complex way you could use [IFTT](https://ifttt.com/) and some mail forwarding procedures to automate the epub generation. This approach is covered in [a blog article](http://danceintech.blogspot.de/2014/11/from-pocket-read-it-later-to-kindle.html) on the tech blog "Dancing in Technology"

Answer (score 2):

If you're more interested in a backup (I also use Pocket with my Kobo) then I'd suggest signing up to ifttt.com, signing in with your Pocket account, and an Instapaper account (create one if you don't have one). Then, in ifttt.com, you can create a recipe that states that when you save something to Pocket, it also saves to Instapaper.

That will give you one backup. Periodically, you can then go into your Instapaper account and export your articles to PDF, epub, or mobi.

Answer (score -1):

Save as PDF format, then convert PDF to ePub, how about this solution?